# Bar URL error when made a Jquery call to a servlet

Tags: jquery, json, spring, jqgrid

The URL parameter in the `JQuery/Jqgrid` is not getting resolved properly. I'm posting my Java Script file below

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->


var McGuirePortlet = function(nameSpace) {
    var servletURL = '<%=renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath())%>'+"/roster/grid";
    var mThis = $.Portlet.call(this, nameSpace);
    mThis.ready = function() {
        // this method is called when $(document).ready is called
        alert("Coming here");
        $("p").click(function() {
            $(this).hide();
        });
        $("#rosterGrid").jqGrid({
            url: servletURL,    
            datatype: 'json',
            colNames:['Last Name', 'First Name'],
            colModel:[
                   {name:'lastName',index:'firstName asc', width:55},
                   {name:'firstName',index:'firstName', width:55}   
            ],
            rowNum:10,
            rowList:[10,20,30],
            pager: '#roster',
            sortname: 'lastName',
            viewrecords: true,
            sortorder: "desc",
            caption:"JSON Roster Grid"
        });
        jQuery("#rosterGrid").jqGrid('navGrid','#roster',{edit:false,add:false,del:false});
    };
    return mThis;
};
jQuery.registerPortlet(new McGuirePortlet("<portlet:namespace />"));
```

But the URL appears weird because the 
`<%=renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath())%>` within the javascript is not getting resolved properly.

Also I noticed that in the FireBug javascript console, the response window shows XML Tab (next to Response) and not JSON but I'm expecting a JSON response. Attached the snapshot please refer.

Have been struggling to get this resolved. Looking forward your help.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess the file you posted is a `js` file. But what you tryed (`<%=renderResponse.encodeURL(renderRequest.getContextPath())%>`) is only evaluated in jsp files.

Two different workarounds:

- pass the url as an parameter from an jsp file to the script.
- rename the file to something like `my.js.jsp`, and then use some kind of url mapping to map the url `my.js` to the `my.js.jsp` file.

Comment: Thanks much, it added the mentioned js code in jsp but it resolves to the following `http://localhost:8080/McGuirePortlet/roster/grid?_search=false&nd=1325843369982&rows=10&page=1&sidx=lastName&sord=desc` which gives a http 404 error eventhough I have a servlet with servlet mapping "/roster/*". It is a spring controller with @ResponseBody which writes the response back as json string. But not sure why it does not work

Comment: @Arvind this seams to be an other problem. Raise a new question, containing the url that you invoke, the controller, the exact exception message, as well as everything that is important to that subject or uncommon.

Answer (score 0):

Try the below steps.
Configure the servlet in your web.xml like,

```
<servlet>
        <description>Somedesc</description>
        <display-name>Somename</display-name>
        <servlet-name>Servletname</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>com.packge1.Servletname</servlet-class>
  </servlet>
  <servlet-mapping>
     <servlet-name>Servletname</servlet-name>
     <url-pattern>/Servletname</url-pattern>
  </servlet-mapping>
```

And pass the url as /servletname from the jqgrid url.